# Issue with global variable in BuilderNavbarService being overwritten

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, subscription

I have a feature in my app which allows a user to change the colour of a component in real-time.

However I am running into some issues.

Whenever the colour of a component is changed, it is not possible for the user to reset the component colour back to default.

The global variables which hold the configuration seem to be overwritten by the changes made, even though they are loaded in a file.

The user can continue changing the colour of the component, but when `setDefaultNavbarTemplate` is called, the style cannot revert back to what it was previously.

**Code below:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { ActiveTemplates } from '../../builder';
import DefaultTemplate from 'src/assets/data/web-templates/web-template-default.json';

@Injectable()
export class BuilderNavbarService {
  DEFAULT_NAVBAR_STYLE = DefaultTemplate['navbarStyle'];
  DEFAULT_NAVBAR_LINK_STYLE = DefaultTemplate['navbarLinkStyle'];
  DEFAULT_NAVBAR_BRAND_STYLE = DefaultTemplate['navbarBrandStyle'];

  navbarTemplate = new BehaviorSubject<string>(ActiveTemplates.Default);
  navbarStyle = new BehaviorSubject<Object>(null);
  navbarLinkStyle = new BehaviorSubject<Object>(null);
  navbarBrandStyle = new BehaviorSubject<Object>(null);

  setNavbarTemplate(templateId: string) {
    switch (templateId) {
      case ActiveTemplates.Default:
        this.navbarTemplate.next(ActiveTemplates.Default);
        this.navbarStyle.next(this.DEFAULT_NAVBAR_STYLE);
        this.navbarLinkStyle.next(this.DEFAULT_NAVBAR_LINK_STYLE);
        this.navbarBrandStyle.next(this.DEFAULT_NAVBAR_BRAND_STYLE);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  setDefaultNavbarTemplate(templateId: string) {
    switch (templateId) {
      case ActiveTemplates.Default:
        this.navbarTemplate.next(ActiveTemplates.Default);
        this.navbarStyle.next(DefaultTemplate['navbarStyle']);
        this.navbarLinkStyle.next(DefaultTemplate['navbarLinkStyle']);
        this.navbarBrandStyle.next(DefaultTemplate['navbarBrandStyle']);
        break
      default:
        break
    }
  }
}
```

I can get around it by doing this, but I'm not sure why this works, as the variable `DefaultTemplate` holds the same values:

```
setDefaultNavbarTemplate(templateId: string) {
    if (templateId == ActiveTemplates.Default) {
      const navbarStyle = {
        'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
      };
      const navbarLinkStyle = {
        'color': '#000'
      };
      const navbarBrandStyle = {
        'color': '#757575'
      };
      this.navbarTemplate.next(ActiveTemplates.Default);
      this.navbarStyle.next(navbarStyle);
      this.navbarLinkStyle.next(navbarLinkStyle);
      this.navbarBrandStyle.next(navbarBrandStyle);
    }
}
```

This is the content of `web-template-default.json`:

```
{
  "id": "web-template-default",
  "navbarStyle": {
    "background-color": "#FFFFFF"
  },
  "navbarLinkStyle": {
    "color": "#000"
  },
  "navbarBrandStyle": {
    "color": "#757575"
  }
}
```

This is the code that does the colour swap:

```
export class NavbarColourPickerComponent implements OnInit {
  isMobile: Observable<BreakpointState>;

  // Set the default style
  navbarStyle: any = {
    'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
  };
  navbarBrandStyle: any = {
    'color': '#757575'
  };
  navbarLinkStyle: any = {
    'color': '#000'
  };
  navbarTemplate: string = ActiveTemplates.Default;

  private navbarStyleSubscription: Subscription;
  private navbarBrandStyleSubscription: Subscription;
  private navbarLinkStyleSubscription: Subscription;
  private navbarTemplateSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
    private builderNavbarService: BuilderNavbarService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isMobile = this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Handset]);
    this.navbarStyleSubscription = this.builderNavbarService.navbarStyle.subscribe(response => {
      if (response) {
        this.navbarStyle = response;
      }
    });
    this.navbarBrandStyleSubscription = this.builderNavbarService.navbarBrandStyle.subscribe(response => {
      if (response) {
        this.navbarBrandStyle = response;
      }
    });
    this.navbarLinkStyleSubscription = this.builderNavbarService.navbarLinkStyle.subscribe(response => {
      if (response) {
        this.navbarLinkStyle = response;
      }
    });
    this.navbarTemplateSubscription = this.builderNavbarService.navbarTemplate.subscribe(response => {
      if (response) {
        this.navbarTemplate = response;
      }
    });
  }

  setNavbarStyle() {
    this.builderNavbarService.navbarStyle.next(this.navbarStyle);
  }

  setNavbarBrandStyle() {
    this.builderNavbarService.navbarBrandStyle.next(this.navbarBrandStyle);
  }

  setNavbarLinkStyle() {
    this.builderNavbarService.navbarLinkStyle.next(this.navbarLinkStyle);
  }

  resetToDefault() {
    this.builderNavbarService.setDefaultNavbarTemplate(this.navbarTemplate);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show the `DefaultTemplate` object?

Comment: yup its `web-template-default.json`

Comment: The reference of the `DEFAULT_NAVBAR_STYLE` is shared across files. I can't see in the current code where it happens that you overwrite the style objects inside the template, but you should treat is as read only. Can you make a stackblitz to reproduce the issue?